# When I start and stop mongod process all data is los

Tags: mongodb

I'm a newbie in MongoDB.
I start `mongod` then I launch `mongosh` I insert some data and finally I type

```
db.adminCommand({shutdown: 1})
```

I stoped mongod process and I started it again, but when I launch `mongosh` data is disappeared! Collections and its documents are gone!

Comment: How do you start the MongoDB? Did you install a service which starts automatically at boot time?